# PHP seo freindly url - I want to remove %20 by '-' in my php url

Tags: .htaccess

I want help in remove %20 from my url .
My Current url is http://www.searchbankifsccode.com/STATE%20BANK%20OF%20INDIA

The url i want is http://www.searchbankifsccode.com/STATE-BANK-OF-INDIA

my index page code is give below.

```
  <?php
    function create_slug($string){
    $slug=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string);
    return $slug;
    }?>

<div id="list"> 
                        <ul>
                            <?php
                            $query = "SELECT DISTINCT `bank` FROM `banks` ORDER BY bank asc";
                            $res = mysqli_query($checkcon, $query);
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                                ?>
                                <li>
                                     <a href="http://www.searchbankifsccode.com/<?php echo $row["bank"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["bank"]; ?></a>
                                </li>

                                <?php
                            }
                            ?> 
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

my htaccess codes are

Options +FollowSymLinks

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ state.php?bnakname=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ district.php?bnakname=$1&statename=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ branch.php?bnakname=$1&statename=$2&districtname=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ifsc.php?bnakname=$1&statename=$2&districtname=$3&branchname=$4 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these 2 rows. Check if helps:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^([^/]*?)(?:/|%20)+([^/]+?(?:/|%20)+.*)$"
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1-%2 [N,NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^([^/]*?)(?:/|%20)+([^/]+?)/?$"
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1-%2/ [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks Andrii, I placed your code in my .htaccess file but that dosen't change anything, The problem is same.